# Finger and face tracking using ARKit 3

Tags: ios, arkit, face-detection

Is finger tracking supported by ARKit 3? And if yes, can ARKit 3 be used in conjunction with the face detection API for the TrueDepth Camera module to sport the position of a certain finger in respect to eyes, nose and mouth?
If not, is there an easy way for finger tracking using, without going as deep as using Metal APIs?

**Note:** by finger tracking, I mean tracking the number of fingers and/or which finger(s) is visible.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that you can get pretty close positions for the fingers of a tracked body using ARKit 3's human body tracking feature (see Apple's [Capturing Body Motion in 3D](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/capturing_body_motion_in_3d) sample code), but you use [ARBodyTrackingConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arbodytrackingconfiguration) for the human body tracking feature, and face tracking is not supported under that configuration. Also, the joints for fingers are not tracked, so while you can get their approximate location using a joint that is tracked (i.e., the wrist), ARKit won't tell you which fingers are extended or retracted.

Comment: Is it possible to get a position of a finger which is visible in camera? I do not have a device with A12 chip so I want to collect info about it thanks

Comment: ARKit (v3) won't help you with precise finger tracking. I would explore using Core ML instead. However, that requires you to find (or train your own) machine learning model that does the finger detection for you. If you have such a model, see the [Recognizing and Labeling Arbitrary Objects](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/recognizing_and_labeling_arbitrary_objects) sample code to integrate it with ARKit.